# problem when restoring port in xampp virtual host with valet installed

Tags: php, xampp, virtualhost, valet

I've been working on a project and it's been fine so far (I can access `http://local.mySitev2_b.com` and `dev.mySite.com`), but recently I started following a laravel tutorial video where it uses `valet` so I needed to change the port setting for the XAMPP. now my old projects can't be accessed anymore. Any idea what I'm missing or what I'm doing wrong?

Folder structure in `F:\Project` where I set up my virtual hosts for the old projects is like this:

```
F > Project
    > mySite
    > anotherWebsite
  > applications
    > app-01
    > app-02
```

this is my `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       dev.mySite.com
127.0.0.1:8080       local.mySitev2_b.com
```

this is my `httpd-vhosts.conf` file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080
#
#
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "F:/Project"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "F:/Project/mySite/"
    ServerName dev.mySite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

in `httpd.conf` I already set this:

```
#Listen 80
Listen 8080
```

here's what I tried:

- creating a new folder and file in `C:\xampp\htdocs\newProject\index.html` containing this one line of code `<h1>Hello World</h1>`
- running the command `valet forget` in `F:\Project`
- deleting the `"F:\\Project"` in `~\.config\valet\config.json` file

but when I try to open `localhost` in my browser, it just shows this page:
[image: 404 not found]

this is when I try to open `localhost:8080`
[image: localhost:8080]

this is when I try to open `local.mySitev2_b.com` or `local.mySitev2_b.com:8080`
[image: can't connect to server]